# Cutoff point detection question

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, calibration

Suppose I have two methods $A$ and $B$ that can be used to measure the value $y$ for an outcome variable given the value of an explanatory value $x$.

The following figure shows the scatter-plot of the difference between $y$ values from those two methods ($y_B - y_A$) against $x$ based on one experiment.

[image]

Method $A$ is the gold-standard approach, so the outcome values it produces are regarded as true values. But this method is more complicated and expensive as compared to method $B$. On the other hand, method $B$ is sort of an approximation, and might be not statistically accurate as compared to method $A$. Therefore, the collaborators wish to know within which range of $x$ that method $B$ can be used as surrogate to measure the outcome. Suppose that we wish to have that range as wide as possible. Due to the nature of the problem, $x$ is randomly distributed in the range [0, 0.2]. Out of that range, the outcome is not meaningful nor measurable.

Based on the plot, we can clearly see method $B$ produced positively biased outcome values at small $x$. The smaller $x$ is, the large is the bias. And it seems that within range [0.1, 0.2] of $x$, Method $B$ does a good job.

To quantitatively find the cut-off, suppose I pick a cut-off point $c$, and take data in the range $[c, 0.2]$ and do a paired-t test of the $y$ values. If I don't observe significance. Could I then conclude that method $B$ is applicable in this range?

My concerns about it is that the insignificance may be due to the cancellation of the positive bias at lower end and the negative bias at the upper end, which may not imply method $B$ is accurate enough. Should this still be a concern if $X$ is randomly distributed in the range? Statistically speaking, what would be a more rigorous approach to address this question?

Comment: It would be more useful to predict $y_A$ based on $(x, y_B)$. The scatterplot suggests the predictability is no worse (and maybe even better) at smaller $x$ than at larger $x$. There are some intriguing patterns that deserve comment or explanation: in particular, it appears $y_B-y_A$ might have to fall within finite limits determined by $x$. If this is the case, why? One also wonders whether the difference is the best way to assess discrepancies. Why not a relative difference or ratio?

Comment: There don't appear to be very many observations at the lowest values of X, which might pose a problem. I don't know what you mean precisely by "x is randomly distributed in the range [0, 0.2]" but it certainly isn't uniformly distributed over that range.

Comment: @whuber. Because of the nature of the problem, $x$ has to be within the range $[0, 0.2]$. otherwise $y$ is not meaningful. My collaborator only wish to establish the equivalence of method A and B within a certain range. Your comments make me think that maybe we need to further look at the problem as a prediction one, not just testing equivalence. Awesome. Thanks much.

Comment: @EdM. Thanks for the comment. The distribution of X is by assumption. Maybe we need to test that as well.

Comment: @whuber. If we just wish to address the problem as establishing equivalence of two methods within a interval. Would the solution I mentioned be statistically meaningful and applicable?

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't, Aaron--it's not an appropriate use of the t-test. I don't understand your remark about $x$ being in a limited range (because you already had made that clear): I was asking why the differences between $y_A$ and $y_B$ appear to be in a limited range. It would help to understand what kinds of measurements these might be. It also seems to me that you could view this problem as one of *calibrating* method $B$ to method $A$, which I think would be a more constructive approach than just determining the range of $x$ for which calibration is not needed.

Comment: @whuber, got it. I will think it through more carefully.